# How can i replace {code} or {noformat} Wikitext with <code> tags

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to take the Jira case details / comments and use the details in our support / utility system and want to replace {code} and {noformat} tags with `<code></code>`
tags so that the formatting is similar to what is shown in Jira

I have tried a few regex expressions with no luck so far.

Here is what I have tried so far

`/({code}(?:(?!{code}).)*){code}((?:(?!{code}).)*)/` to replace every other {code} tage with `</code>`  and `/{code}/` to then replace the remaining {code} tags with `<code>`

This also does not take into account the chance that a {code} tag may have {noformat} tags inside and these should not be replaced or vice versa.

Here is the same code I am working with

```php
$jira = new JiraClient\JiraClient('https://jira.url', 'myUser', 'myPass');
try {

    $issue = $jira->issue()->get($ticketJira);

    //$caseBody = $issue->getDescription()

    //For testing Let's Hardset the caseBody

    $caseBody = 'Example Code: {code}{ "fields": { "project": { "key": "JIRA" }, "summary": "Build Jira API into Support Interface to help raise cases.", "description": "Creating of an issue using project\\r\\nkeys and issue type names using the REST API\\r\\n{code}Markup Test{code}", "issuetype": { "name": "Production Task/Issue" }, "customfield_10800": [{"value":"Not applicable"}], "fixVersions": [{"name":"3.0.136.2"},], "versions": [{"name":"3.0.136.2"},] } }{code}';

    // Replace {code} / noformat tags here
      $descRaw = $issue->getDescription();
      $despPre = preg_replace('/({code}+)/', '<code>', $descRaw,1);
      $desc = preg_replace('/(.*(?:(?!{code}).)*){code}((?:(?!.*).)*)/', '\\1</code>\\2', $despPre);


    echo('<label class="control-label">'.$issue->getKey().' - '.$issue->getSummary().'</label>');
    echo("<p class='modal-content' style='text-align: left !important;'>".nl2br($desc)."</p>");
    echo('');
}
catch (\JiraClient\Exception\JiraException $e) {
    echo('<p>'.$e.'></p>');
}
```

The 2 issues I am having are, the inline tags are also being converted and that I would also want this to work with {noformat} tags instead of having to do a second pass.

Comment: I'm not seeing any attempt to solve the problem in your code, or a clear description of the desired output. What we need to see is your sample text `$caseBody = ...`, desired outcome, and some attempt to solve the problem yourself. None of the other code there is relevant to your problem.

Comment: I have update the code with the latest test that works on a basic level but not 100%

Comment: Still searching for the current output and the wanted output.

Answer (score 0):

This one should do what you want: `{code}(.*?){code}`. Associated to `preg_replace()`, it will replace all `{code}` occurences by `<code>` (or `</code>` if a previous one is found).

An example which also replaces `{noformat}` by `<code>`:

```php
$str = '{code}var a = 1;{code} then, {noformat}a = 5;{noformat} and, {code}a -= 4;{code}';

$codePatterns = [
    '/{code}(.*?){code}/',
    '/{noformat}(.*?){noformat}/'
];

// output: <code>var a = 1;</code> then, <code>a = 5;</code> and, <code>a -= 4;</code>
echo preg_replace($codePatterns, '<code>$1</code>', $str);
```

[Test this snippet on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/defXR)

---

**Explanation of the regular expression:**

- `{code}` matches literally `{code}`
- `(.*?)`...

  - `()` captures the content between for later use
  - `.` matches any character, except for new line
  - `*?` matches between zero and unlimited times the previous character, as few times as possible
- `{code}` matches literally `{code}`

*Note:* If I used `.*` instead of `.*?`, the output would be:

```html
<code>var a = 1;{code} then, <code>a = 5;</code> and, {code}a -= 4;</code>
```

I guess that's why you ended with a such complicated expression.

Comment: That is a lot better than what I came up with but there is still an issue where ` {code}{noformat}{noformat}{code}` becomes `<code><code></code></code>`  is there a way to make it ignore {noformat} until it hits a second {code}? Eg `<code>{noformat}{noformat}</code>` or when using {noformat} `<code>{code}{code}</code>`.

I tried the following but this seems to only pickup the very first and last tags rather than pairs
`{noformat}(.*){noformat}(?![^{code}(.*?){code}]*})`

Comment: Also, although this works with Manually setting the $str value as per your example, if I set it via $issue->getDescription(); then preg_replace doesn't match anything. 
Here is the current test I am running - https://regex101.com/r/xW8sL8/21

Comment: The current test you provided has no issue?

Comment: Yeah, I'm wondering if it does something different when pulling from the Jira API